# c# .net Request.Param

Tags: .net, query-string, trim

i think i know the answer to this question, but it never hurts to ask...

our .net application needs to store things like names in the database.
we just discovered some fields with leading spaces.

1) i could go thru every single field we store in the database and trim each value before it goes in. but i really would like to avoid having to do that and forgetting the next time a field is added.

2) another way would be to trim all the request params *before* they are processed into objects in my controller action parameter list. this seems cleanest to me because it would cover any eventuality. however it looks like the request parameters are read only at run time, even though if i write code, the compiler is happy to let me put a param on the lhs.

3) finally, i could trim all the values before they are transmitted to the server. i can do this very easily b/c i'm using extjs and can add a global 'getRawValue()' that trims the string when extracting it from a form field. this is less appealing, more on philosophical grounds: the front end should not have to perform tasks to ensure the database is in good shape.

--

it looks like (3) is the best option (for me). comments?

Comment: Do you use stored procedures to insert/update the database?

Comment: Are you using an ORM or straight ADO.NET?

Comment: @agent-j: we insert/update directly to tables

Comment: @KrisKrause: we use LINQtoSQL, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using MVC. You could use a custom model binder that trims string values when binding the parameters to your action parameters.

The model binder is the service that transforms the Request parameters into actual objects that get passed into your controller actions. See [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) for a good explanation.

While I haven't done this myself, it appears that something like this ought to work:

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        var valString = value as string;
        if(valString != null)
        {
            value = valString.Trim();
        }
        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

You basically just override the default behavior to trim any string value before setting it as the value of an action parameter or a property on an action's parameter.

I haven't figured out how to register this as your default model binder with ASP.NET MVC: that may actually depend on your IoC container.

Comment: thank you. yes, it's mvc. i'm fairly new to mvc, but my understanding of models is that the view displays data from a model. when i search for custom model binding, i see stuff about models and views, not action parameters.. could you put a little more meat on the bones? ;-) thanx!

Comment: @horace: I fleshed it out a bit. I'm afraid I don't have time for more. Do some exploring and see if that works for you.

Comment: thank you for the bigger nudge. that is about what i need. will review this over the next day or two (in all my spare time!) and let you know what i end up doing. -- thx

Comment: Stripling Warrior: if i understand your solution and the link you indicated (plus related links), this is about using reflection to build the incoming objects that comprise parameters for controller methods. this is more than i think should happen to solve my problem. what would be ideal is a *filter* that allows me to modify the incoming parameters *before* they are used to build objects for controller actions.

Comment: @horace: I don't really see why you need to have the values changed any earlier in the lifecycle than this: your action hasn't even been called yet. But you could build a custom IHttpModule that modifies the request information as it's coming in, or you could set up a jquery handler on your forms so when they get submitted the text inputs get trimmed. It's usually better to go with a server-side approach to avoid malicious user input.

Comment: Stripling Warrior: you have identified precisely why i want to change the values. the controller hasn't been invoked and i have fields that go into the database that should not have leading/trailing whitespace .. it isn't as much of a problem for numbers/dates/etc, but i want control over those strings before they become a nuisance. and you're right, handling it on the client side is unappealing. i'll have a look at ihttpmodule to see if it offers the very simple thing i'm interested in.

Comment: @horace: Fields are being saved into the database before your controller action gets invoked? How does that happen?

Comment: Stripling Warrior: no... sorry to confuse. the controller operates as normal. i want the strings trimmed before the object parameters hit the controller action so i don't have to make each orm object strip each and every field one-by-one. have a look at the original question i posted. this is pretty clear.

Comment: @horace: That's what I understood from the original question, and that's what this answer does. Before your action is invoked, MVC asks the model binder to produce the parameters to pass into the action. If that model binder trims the whitespace from any string values, then the action will get invoked with pre-trimmed parameters.

Comment: Stripling Warrior: right. i was just trying to address your question :::Fields are being saved into the database before your controller action gets invoked? How does that happen?::: again. thanks for the answer. my only problem with it is that i have to go thru reflection to get there. _seems_ like there should be another way, maybe there isn't. :-/